# Phonegap v1.0.0 to v1.1.0 : ajax query with external domain return error without use 'ExternalHosts'

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

When i tried to upgrate phonegap 1.0.0 to phonegap 1.1.0, all my jQuery Ajax can't call external website url.

I have an app (iOS and Android) with phonegap 1.0.0 and jquerymobile 1.0.0 who call a webservice to get some websites's URL list to use in this app. These URL are called with jquery ajax who return the html code of these websites.
All works perfectly with phonegap 1.0.0.

After update phonegap on v1.1.0 all ajax queries who call these website URL have returned error with readystate=4.

I found this solution:
If i put domain host in "ExternalHosts" in phonegap.plist, ajax queries have return the html code of this domain.

But is not a good solution for me because the URL list recovered by my webservice can changed everyday. I can't make a new app with a new domain in "ExternalHosts" in phonegap.plist every day.

Is that all new versions of PhoneGap (next 1.0.0) need to fix ajax query (call external website url) with "ExternalHosts"?

Someone have tested ajax query with external website url on latest Phonegap version?

for the moment i downgrade my phonegap version on 1.0.0.... :-(

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Why are you upgrading to an old version? The current version of PhoneGap is 1.7: http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know all the hosts that your app may connect to then you will want to use the "*" wildcard for "ExternalHosts" in your .plist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on the jQuery Mobile documentation that describes steps to take when creating a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Basically the whole page is good information (otherwise I would have copied the specific text).

Comment: I didn't have to put the code: $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; on my app with PhoneGap 1.0.0

Comment: In Cordova user guide v1.7 :
"To upgrade from 1.3.0 to 1.6.x, please go to the 1.4.0 instructions first, then 1.5.0, then 1.6.x, then 1.7.0"

I am on 1.0.0, Do you think i can jump on v1.7 without going step by step like the guide says?

Comment: To your first comment, I didn't have issues with 1.0 either but things can change. To your second comment. You're so many versions behind I would create a new App in your IDE and copy the source from your old one to the new one but with the new version of PhoneGap.